# Can we use gtid mode without enabling enforce_gtid_consistency? Is it safe?

Tags: mysql

If I set `gtid_mode = on` and `enforce_gtid_consistency=off`, the operations that are not allowed to use gtid is still replicated in other ways?

From mysql documentation:

> Only statements that can be logged using GTID safe statements can be
> logged when enforce_gtid_consistency is set to ON, so the operations
> listed here cannot be used with this option:
>
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE or DROP TEMPORARY TABLE statements inside
> transactions.
>
> Transactions or statements that update both transactional and
> nontransactional tables. There is an exception that nontransactional
> DML is allowed in the same transaction or in the same statement as
> transactional DML, if all nontransactional tables are temporary.
>
> CREATE TABLE ... SELECT statements, prior to MySQL 8.0.21. From MySQL
> 8.0.21, CREATE TABLE ... SELECT statements are allowed for storage engines that support atomic DDL.

If setting `enforce_gtid_consistency=off`, those transactions that cannot use gtid are replicated in some other way, but all other transactions are replicated using gtid? How it works?

Answer (score 0):

I just create a lab to test it, and find out we even can't enable gtid_mode to on when enforce_gtid_consistency=off is off.

```
ERROR 3111 (HY000): SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = ON is not allowed because ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY is not ON.
```